# strange behavior using $('.ajax_form').ajaxForm();

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

It is my first time to apply jquery ajaxForm on a class like the following

```
<form class="ajax_form"...><input type="text" name="q" /><input type="submit" /></form>
<form class="ajax_form"...><input type="text" name="q" /><input type="submit" /></form>

<script>
$('.ajax_form').ajaxForm({
  dataType: 'json',
  error: ajaxErrorHandler,
  success: function(response) { // do some ui update .. }
});
</script>
```

Now after Ajax call is completed I **always get into error section** although firebug didn't report any errors response not sure what I did wrong.

Answer (score 11):

This may or not be appropriate in this case, but I'll provide it because it would have been useful to me when I was searching for the answer to a similar problem. If you are submitting a "multipart/form-data" form with file upload in Firefox, jquery.form will use an iframe to submit the form.  If the Content-Type of your return data is text/plain, the iframe will wrap the resulting text in <pre> tags which will hork the jquery json parser and give you a parser error even though Firebug shows the response and even the json correctly.

This caused me no end of headaches before I figured it out (with help from this thread: http://www.extjs.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-17248.html).

The answer in my case was to make sure the response Content-Type was "text/html" (which was counter-intuitive, at least for me).

Comment: +1 because your answer helped me confirm an issue I have with iframe.  And also hork - I like that word.

Answer (score 1):

@c.sokun: Using a class shouldn't be a problem here, as long as there's only 1 form using the class. Two forms with the same class on the same page will definitely cause a hiccup (refer to your code... or is it a typo?)

Have you tried using **[FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/)** and checked the parameters passed and the values returned? That should be the first!

Comment: the reason I use class because I had multiple form which I need to convert it to ajaxForm; I check response header in FireBug it was json as expected.

Comment: Ok. Try this... remove the class from one of the forms... leaving only one matching form in your DOM. See if the function executes successfully. Then you can be sure that it's got something to do with two consecutive ajax submissions and take a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your json data. These are probably not well formed and can't be parsed. In that case the success function won't be called.

You can verify this if you print the messages of the error callback. Use the following code:

```
url = url + "?" + $(".ajaxForm").serialize();
$(".ajaxForm").ajax({url: url, dataType: "json", type : "post",
                    success: function(response) {},
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }});
```

One of the print-outs should be something like "parser error".

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need a url and post type for the form to send the data somewhere?

this is how they set it up on [jquery.com](http://docs.jquery.com/Types#Options):

```
$("#myform").ajaxForm({
   url: "mypage.php",
   type: "POST"
 });
```

Comment: well, I remove the action="" from the form for clarity but the problem was not on the submission part but on the callback function.

Comment: and the issue here is also note I do not use DOM ID but class instead which I suspect causing this strange behavior.

Comment: Have you tried giving one of the divs an id, and call an update on just one? That might help you see if there is a problem calling multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

Is ajaxErrorHandler defined elsewhere?
I tried your code, and it worked perfectly. What version of jQuery and jQuery form are you using?

This is the code I tried. With a file named 'test.json' containing "{test:'hello world'}" in the same directory as this test:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.com/jquery/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.com/jquery/form/jquery.form.js?2.28"></script>

<form class="ajax_form" action="test.json" method="post"><input type="text" name="q" /><input type="submit" /></form>
<br/>
<form class="ajax_form" action="test.json" method="post"><input type="text" name="q" /><input type="submit" /></form>

<script>
$('.ajax_form').ajaxForm({
  dataType: 'json',
  error: function() {alert("error");},
  success: function(response) {alert(response.test);}
});
</script>
```

Comment: I used the latest version of jQuery which is 1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've checked in API and didn't find any reference to options field called "error", so probably thats the reason. Check [here](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api).