# ajaxForm: how to get rid of '<pre>' and '</pre>' in the response?

Tags: ajax, json, ajaxform

I've read and also applied some similar solutions, but so far not get working well.

html

```
<form id="update-form" action="/update" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file" single />
  <input type="submit" value="submit />
</form>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#update-form').ajaxForm( {
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    } );
  } );
</script>
```

sinatra

```
post '/update' do
  ...
  content_type :json
  { :success => true }.to_json
end
```

When I run this, after clicking "submit", I receive in alert:

```
<pre>{"success":true}</pre>
```

This "pre" thing is really annoying which prevents proper call of parseJSON. I could do some string manipulation to remove it. But I would like to have better solution.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: come on, no answer to that?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just answer myself,

similar to this question

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908975/strange-behavior-using-ajax-form-ajaxform
```

and follow the link to this

```
http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-17248.html
```

Short answer,

change "content_type :json" to "content_type :html"

then "pre" will disappear